# Cordova App: Wakelock,Service or AlarmManager?

Tags: cordova, android-service, alarmmanager, wakelock

I've written my first phonegap application that checks if the phone is in a certain radius around a predefined location and if so, plays a sound.
Works great, except that if my phone turns into standby or app goes into background it stops working.

If i get into the radius the phone should wake up and display my app.

So i came up with three options:

Wakelock: 
As i see that, wakelocks only solve the problem of standby,
if i switch app and then my phone goes into standby i again have my problem?

Service: 
Not quite sure about that, seems like a service can not wake up my phone?

AlarmManager:
Can wake my phone, but can it run my app in background and check my position?

As you can see a lot of questions. So which method would be the best one. 
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Comment: couldn't solve it till now ? Anyone for help ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Geofencing: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

You specify a Lat/Long/Radius, and the app is triggered appropriately.

Good luck!